# How to copy the elements of the list within the list?

Tags: python, list, copy

I have a list `list_1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], ....]`. I want `[[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [7,8,9]]`. How can i achieve this?
Its like basically copying each element of the list to its consecutive index.

Comment: I cannot understand your question. Can you be a little more clear?

Comment: I want ith element of my list to be copied to i+1the location. For eg: [a,b,c]--> [a,a,b,b,c,c]

Comment: What did you try? [mre]? Where is your problem? Why is [1,2,3] only at indexes 0 and 1? why is it at index 0 at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from copy import deepcopy

def multiply_list_elem(lst, n):
    out = list()
    for elem in lst:
        for _ in range(n):
            out.append(deepcopy(elem))
    return out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
    print(multiply_list_elem(list_1, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be something like:

## Using reference

```
def double(some_list): 
    return_list = [] 
    for element in some_list: 
             return_list.append(element) 
             return_list.append(element) 
    return return_list
# example call
l = [1,[2, 42]]
print(double(l))
# output: [1,1,[2,42],[2,42]]
```

using the second for loop can be done, but is slower. Therefore I recommend not using it unless you want to have a variable multiplier as presented in Félix Herbinet's solution.

## Using (deep)copy

Since the question explicitly contains the word copying, I will also show a copy version:

```
import copy

def double(some_list): 
    return_list = [] 
    for element in some_list: 
             return_list.append(copy.deepcopy(element)) 
             return_list.append(copy.deepcopy(element)) 
    return return_list
# example call
l = [1,[2, 42]]
print(double(l))
# output: [1,1,[2,42],[2,42]]
```

If you are unsure whether you need copy or deepcopy read this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#shallow-vs-deep-copy

Comment: can you explain what the problem is you are seeing? I added a call example

Answer (score 0):

First declare another list `double` and then modify `double` with two elements for each element of `lst`.
You can remove the `lst = double` statement, if you don't want to modify the original list.
Sample code:

```py
def multiply(lst):
    double = [];
    for i in lst:
        for j in range(2):
            double.append(i);
    lst = double;
    return lst;
```

Comment: if used like `list_2 = multiply(list_1)` you have a problem:   `list_2[1][1] = 42; print(list_2)` - this is also essentially the same as the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71319602/7505395

Answer (score -1):

You can use this as iterative process:

```
list_1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
list_2 = []
for element in list_1:
  for times in range(2):
    list_2.append(element)
```

Or this for list comprehension:

Comment: if used like `list_2 = multiply(list_1)` you have a problem: `list_2[1][1] = 42; print(list_2)` - this is also essentially the same as the answer stackoverflow.com/a/71319602/7505395 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/71319754/7505395

Answer (score -1):

You could double the list, then sort based on the first index of the sublists:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from copy import deepcopy

list_1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

list_2 = sorted(list_1 + deepcopy(list_1), key = itemgetter(0))
```

Comment: missing import + Problem:   `list_2[1][1] = 42; print(list_2)`

Comment: You're right, I edited it